# I can't input a string in c

Tags: c, string, input

So I've tried so much but I can't input a string even using: `fgets`, `gets`, `scanf`, and `scanf("%[^\n]%*c",pharse)`. I need a string with the spaces. It just jumps the code line of input I think.
Please answer with a explanation of why it doesn't work

https://repl.it/@YashKumar11/String#main.c

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int main(void) {

    const int DIMMAX=100;
    char pharse[DIMMAX+1];
    int stringLength;
    int choice=0;

    while(choice != '5'){
        printf("1)Enter a new pharse.");
        printf("\n2)");
        printf("\n3)");
        printf("\n4)");
        printf("\n5)\n");
        scanf("%d",&choice);

        switch(choice){
        case 1:
            printf("\n=====================\n");            
            scanf ("%[^\n]%*c",pharse); //<-----------------------It jumps here 
            printf("\n=====================\n");
            stringLength = strlen(pharse);
            printf("%s",pharse);

            break;      

        case 2:
            break; 
      
        case 3:
            break; 

        case 4:
            break; 

        case 5:
            break; 

        default:
            printf("\nNot a valid option.\n\n");
            break;
        }
    }

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: `%[^\n]` is reading an empty string, because the next character in the input stream is `\n`

Comment: You need to skip over the newline first.

Comment: Why not `fgets` if you want to read a line? Using `scanf` for everything is a bad habit to get into.

Comment: @barmar: (Pedantry alert) `%[^\n]` fails; it does not read an empty string. The difference is that the corresponding value argument is not changed to an empty string.

Comment: OT: regarding: `int stringLength;` and `stringLength = strlen(pharse);`  the function: `strlen()` returns a `size_t`, not a `int`.   The result of the posted code is a comparison between a signed and a unsigned value.  This will work most of the time, but should not be relied upon.  Also, the variable `stringLength` is set, but never used

Comment: regarding: `const int DIMMAX=100;`  This is NOT C++.  suggest, immediately after the `#include` statements insert the statement: `#define DIMMAX 100`

Comment: OT:  regarding: `scanf ("%[^\n]%*c",pharse);`  1) this can overrun the input array. the `%[^\n]` needs a MAX CHARACTERS modifier that is one less than the length of the input field.  1 less becaust the %[] input format conversion specifier always appends a NUL byte to the input.  2) Always check the returned value to assure the operation was successful. If not successful, then inform the user through`stderr`.   Suggest: `if( scanf ( "%99[^\n]%*c", pharse ) != 1)  { fprintf( stderr, "scanf for pharse failed\n" );  exit( EXIT_FAILURE ); }`

Comment: OT: regarding: `scanf("%d",&choice);` the checking for success considerations exist

Comment: @user3629249 In C, given `const int DIMMAX=100; char pharse[DIMMAX+1];`, `pharse` is a VLA (variable length array), because `DIMMAX` is not a constant expression. (It is in C++, but `constexpr` would be clearer.) VLAs are not supported in C90, are supported in C99, and are optional in C11, so should be avoided in portable C code.  Another solution: `enum { DIMMAX=100 };` (a trick that's limited to constants of type `int`).

Answer (score 0):

the statement to input the `parase` fails because the input for `choice` leaves a `\n` in the input stream.

When the second call to `scanf()` is made, it immediately returns (with a returned value of 0) because the first character input is `\n`.

suggest following each call to `scanf()` with:

```
int ch;
while( (ch = getchar()) != '\n' && ch != EOF );
```

that also implies that the format string of the second call to `scanf()` should have the `%*c` removed.

Answer (score 0):

Your problem is not in the line that you try to read the string, but in the previous call to `scanf()`

`scanf()` was written to scanf formatted input. Keyboard input is not that. It can be everything except formatted. The user has over 100 keys to choose from

When the user types a '1' to input a phrase scanf() does not consume the newline. In fact the user can type `1 here we go to enter some text!`
and then ENTER. And scanf() will be ok with just the '1'. The rest of the chars would be left there for the program to read. `scanf()` has no way to know what is left there.
Also `scanf()` return an `int` with the number of values read, and it can be zero if the user entered no digits. And you did not tested in your code.

Compare with your code a bit modified below

```
#define     DIMMAX 100

#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int main(void) {

    char phrase[DIMMAX + 1];
    int stringLength;

    printf("1) Enter a new phrase");
    printf("\n2)");
    printf("\n3)");
    printf("\n4)");
    printf("\n5) Exit\n\nOption: ");
    fgets(phrase, DIMMAX, stdin);

    while (phrase[0] != '5')
    {

        switch (phrase[0]) {
        case '1':
            printf("\n=====================\n");
            fgets(phrase, DIMMAX, stdin);
            printf("\n=====================\n");
            stringLength = strlen(phrase);
            phrase[strlen(phrase) - 1] = 0; // deletes the '\n'
            printf("Phrase: '%s', len = %zd\n\n", phrase, strlen(phrase));

            break;

        case '2':
            break;

        case '3':
            break;

        case '4':
            break;

        case '5':
            break;

        default:
            printf("\n'%c' (dec %d) is not a valid option.\n\n",
                phrase[0], phrase[0]);
            break;
        }
        printf("1) Enter a new phrase");
        printf("\n2)");
        printf("\n3)");
        printf("\n4)");
        printf("\n5) Exit\n\nOption: ");
        fgets(phrase, DIMMAX, stdin);
    };  // while()

    return 0;
}
```

Maybe it helps to understand.

Note that instead of stopping rigth at the digit, like `scanf()`, `fgets()` read up to and including the newline, so if you are using `printf()` and not `puts()` to output it, you must take the last byte off the string read